# JQuery hover doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a JQuery hover but it doesnt show. The dimmed-item class, is what I would like to add on to the kunden-item class. Bouth of them allready work if I manuely put them in. JQuery is allready in the File so there must be some logic mistake I made.

Here my HTML for 1 Element:

```
<div class="kunden-item kunde2-item">
  <img class="kunde" src="<?php echo $params->get('image2');?>" alt="Kunde">
</div>
```

Here my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("kunden-item")
  .mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass("dimmed-item");
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("dimmed-item");
  });
});
```

Comment: Change `$("kunden-item")` to `$(".kunden-item")`.

Comment: The question title can be improved...

Comment: I don't think it can. It's a really simple mistake with a really simple solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kunden-item` is a class, so your selector needs a leading `.`:

```
$(".kunden-item")
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).addClass("dimmed-item");
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("dimmed-item");
    });
});
```

Also note that you can massively shorten your code by using `hover()` and `toggleClass()`:

```
$(".kunden-item").hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('dimmed-item');
});
```

Or just by using CSS alone:

```
.kunden-item:hover {
    opacity: 0.5; // for example only, apply whatever style you need here
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Class selectors begin with a `.`

You have a type selector and are trying to match `<kunden-item>` *elements*.

You should have:

```
$(".kunden-item")
```

You can *probably* get rid of the JS entirely and just use a `:hover` rule in your stylesheet though.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a dot (.) before kunden-item. You can also use .hover(), which works like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $(".kunden-item")
      .hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("dimmed-item");
      },
      function() {
        $(this).removeClass("dimmed-item");
      });
    });
```